# Customizing the layout of gdb-many-windows

Tags: window, gud

I really like all of the information that is available to me when I run GUD/GDB with `gdb-many-windows`, but I would like to be able to move the windows around some.  Specifically I would like to use the following layout

```
  +-----------------------+------------------+------------+
  |                       |                  |            |
  |        comint         |  input/output    |            |
  |                       |                  |            |
  +-----------------------+------------------+            |
  |                       |                  |            |
  |                       |     locals       |     sr-    |
  |                       |                  |  speedbar  |
  |        source         |                  |            |
  |                       +------------------+            |
  |                       |                  |            |
  |                       |                  |            |
  |                       |      stack       |            |
  |                       |                  |            |
  |                       |                  |            |
  +-----------------------+------------------+------------+
```

Is there any way that I can customize this so that I always get the same window arrangement every time that I run GDB?

Answer (score 4):

So, the layout itself is hardcoded (as mentioned in the documentation of the `gdb` function). This layout is defined in `gdb-setup-windows`

But then, since it's defined *only* in `gdb-setup-windows`, and that function is called whenever restoring that layout is needed... All you have to do is to override that function to make it generate the layout you fancy !

Obviously, the initial code of `gdb-setup-windows` is a good example of how to write such a function :)