# Change which buffers are in which windows?

Tags: buffers, window, display, window-splitting

I have 3 windows opened and I want to change which buffers they display.

For example: when programming in C, I want to have the C code on the left, and the right side split into two windows showing gdb and the locals variables.  If I open them in order, Emacs puts the buffers in a layout I'm not comfortable with.

How can I arrange which buffers are in which windows?  Can I do it without using non-built-in packages?

Comment: I think you do need a plugin. there's buffer-move.el, about 50 lines of code. Else, i think you'd have to write that yourself.

Comment: I can't understand how Tyler's answer fits the question. I understand the question to be similar to [gud - Customizing the layout of gdb-many-windows - Emacs Stack Exchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/customizing-the-layout-of-gdb-many-windows) and so the answer(s) there might suit you.

Comment: buffer-move.el - not work -  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44187/not-work-package-buffer-move-symbols-value-as-variable-is-void-closed

Answer (score 1):

The [ace-window](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) package provides a function `ace-swap-window` that provides a nice interface for this. When you call the command each window gets a letter label. Type that letter and it will swap the buffers in the current window and the selected window. Variations allow you to select or delete different windows as well.